# Library items in flash reducing export speed

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

At first i was using [Embed] to load in textures for a game.
I then went through the process of moving all the assets into the library.

The program is working fine, however the "Exporting SWF" takes absolutely ages now. It seems like it's doing an awful lot to process these library assets or something.

Is there any way I could reduce this time?

I wish to avoid going back to Embed if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might change your workflow too drastically, but my method to avoid this issue is to compile using a code editor (my preference is [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/), but [FDT](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/) or [Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/flash-builder.html) work too), and to include any assets authored in the Flash Professional IDE by pre-exporting them to an SWC.

It means there are two steps to perform a complete compilation: the first to export the assets from Flash Pro to SWC (which is still slow), and the second to actually compile the SWF using the SWC and your code (which is much quicker). If you edit your assets as often as your code, this won't save you time at all, but in my experience I'll make many more tweaks to the code once the assets are in place, and overall it saves me time.

To start doing this, you can export an SWC from Flash Pro by going to `File` > `Publish Settings`, then checking the 'SWC' option (and unchecking 'SWF'). You can set the SWC path to something convenient for your code editor. Then in FlashDevelop, for example, you would include the SWC in your project (right click and 'Add to Library'), which allows you to access any classes that were set to 'Export for ActionScript' in the Flash Library.

Once it's all set up, I use SHIFT-ALT-F12 to publish from Flash, then tab over to FlashDevelop where the changes will be picked up, ready to compile directly from there.

Comment: Still reading, but I'll say this now, all my assets are pngs, not made in flash.

Comment: I have used flash develop once or twice in the (pretty distant) past. It didn't work for me back then because I was creating all assets in flash. I might look into it again now...

Fortunately I'm only using flash for prototyping so I won't have to deal with this for too long.